# Problemas na instalação do pacote BETS e rbcb

Tags: packages, pyinstaller

Boa tarde!

Estou com problemas na instalação do pacote BETS ( *Brazilian Economic Time Series: Basic Usage*) e rbcb (dados do Banco Central do Brasil por Wilson Freitas).

No primeiro, o R diz que o DBI que eu tenho instalado é 0.5, e a versão que o pacote BETS exige é 1.0.0.

Para o segundo, o R fala que não existe um pacote com nome de rbcb.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver?

Comment: Chegou a dar uma olhada no [repositório](https://github.com/wilsonfreitas/rbcb)? Tem [essa página](http://wilsonfreitas.github.io/posts/rbcb-como-usar.html) do próprio autor que explica como utilizar a lib.

Comment: Opa, amigão, ajudou com rbcb! Muito obrigado! :) Mas ainda continuo tendo problemas com o BETS. ):